# 9 kb memory is leaking in 24 min using Netty

Tags: java, memory-leaks, netty

9184 Bytes memory is leaking in the following code

**Main Class:**

```
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import org.jboss.netty.bootstrap.ServerBootstrap;
import org.jboss.netty.channel.ChannelFactory;
import org.jboss.netty.channel.ChannelPipeline;
import org.jboss.netty.channel.ChannelPipelineFactory;
import org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels;
import org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketChannelFactory;
import org.jboss.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler;
import org.jboss.netty.util.HashedWheelTimer;
import org.jboss.netty.util.Timer;


    public class NettyMemoryLeakTest {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            final Timer timer = new HashedWheelTimer();
            final IdleStateHandler idle = new IdleStateHandler(timer, 0, 0, 1);
            final ChannelFactory cf = new NioServerSocketChannelFactory(Executors.newCachedThreadPool(), Executors.newCachedThreadPool());
            final ServerBootstrap bootStrap = new ServerBootstrap(cf);
            final ServerHandler objServerHandler = new ServerHandler();
            bootStrap.setPipelineFactory(new ChannelPipelineFactory() {
                @Override
                public ChannelPipeline getPipeline() throws Exception {
                    ChannelPipeline pipeline = Channels.pipeline();
                    pipeline.addLast("IDLE", idle);
                    pipeline.addLast("Handler", objServerHandler);
                    return pipeline;

                }
            });

            bootStrap.bind(new InetSocketAddress(8080));

        }
    }
```

**Handler :**

```
import org.jboss.netty.channel.ChannelHandlerContext;
import org.jboss.netty.handler.timeout.IdleState;
import org.jboss.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateAwareChannelHandler;
import org.jboss.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateEvent;

public class ServerHandler extends IdleStateAwareChannelHandler {

    @Override
    public void channelIdle(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, IdleStateEvent e) {
        if (e.getState() == IdleState.ALL_IDLE) {

            System.gc();

        }
    }
}
```

Am using jdk 1.7, netty 3.5.8 Final 
Am checking the memory leack through netbeans profiler. It shows the variation of memory. The memory used

AFTER 48 Min leackage is **2020kb**
please help me to find out the issue

Thank you.

Comment: *"9 kb memory is leaking in 24 min using NETTY"* At that rate, it will take a *very long time(1)* before the JVM would even bother to call GC.  1) At 2Kb per minute it would take around 22 days to fill 64 Meg.

Answer (score 0):

System.gc() will is not guarantee to do a GC at all. If you really think it is a memory leak take a heap-dump in binary form and provide it for inspection.